# Options for analyzing twitter hashtag use by various factors - date of account creation, location, username strings and even defined user lists

Tags: api, tool-request, demographics, scraping

I am not sure if this question is better suited for data science but I'm mostly looking for an outline of what currently is or is not possible and a direction for where I should learn more.

My first interest is if it is possible to look at aspects of who is using a particular hashtag - location and date of account creation, But more importantly if it is possible to separately apply tags to accounts or have lists of accounts that are categorized pre-analysis or manually and see who is using a hashtag.

To explain further - I want to look at everyone who follows one particular account and see how many of them are using a particular hashtag - and then of those that are using the hashtag how many are new accounts? How many are from particular countries? How many have lots of numbers or particular strings in their user names? And how many compare to a list of previously identified trolls for example (or their followers)

I think up to maybe the strings in user names and previously id lists it is possible but I don't know the right words to use to look up what I'm trying to do.

Comment: since you aren't asking about finding the data, and rather asking about its analysis, I'd suggest migrating to DS